# domain specific validation of email in php forms

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to verify the entered email address to be in a specific domain only; for example: only @hotmail.com  emails are accepted.
Here is my code:

```
function valid_email($email) {
    return !!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

I don't know how/where to put the specific domain validation part

Comment: `return !!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && someOtherValidationHere;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your function as follows:

```
function valid_email($email) {
    $result = false;

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $server = strstr($email, '@');
        if ($server == '@hotmail.com') {
            $result = true;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Or in one line:

```
function valid_email($email) {
    return !!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && '@hotmail.com' == strstr($email, '@');
}
```

Info about [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)